# Why doesn't Entity Framework easily allow a custom base class?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Is this a design choice by Microsoft, or is there a way to do it, that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use EF *Entity Objects* as of your entity types then you should have them implement a custom interface in a separate partial class since they are already inheriting from [*EntityObject*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.aspx). 

However, if you use the new EF 4.0 [*POCO Entities*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx), then you can freely have them inherit from ant custom base class that you want.

BTW, this has nothing to do with EF "design", it's just because you cannot have *Multiple Inheritance* in C#.

Comment: I will explore the POCO option. Also I understand that you can't use multiple bases classes, and I have been using interfaces to get things done. It's just that it would be nice if my custom base class could inherit from the EF base class (EntityObject), and I could add actual method implementations within my base class. It sounds like I can do that now with POCO. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The other option would be to favor Composition over inheritance meaning that your entity objects will have a member of your custom base class. It's your call but I would still go with POCOs anyway.

Comment: That's a thought, but I'm definitely going to check out POCO first. I appreciate your insight into this.